# Is there anywhere in the scriptures where it say we should worship God through an Idol?

Tags: worship

On another question it has been stated that Idols are not worshipped but God is worshipped via Idol.  Which scriptures say worship God via Idol

It has been pointed out that Veda says not allowed to worship statue (see below), ***but I have been informed we can worship God via Idol?***

(arguable not correct translation) however, does not effect question - evidence of scriptures worship via idol.

"Andhatama pravishanti ye asambhuti mupaste"

"They enter darkness, those who worship the natural elements" (Air, Water, Fire, etc.). "They sink deeper in darkness, those who worship sambhuti." [Yajurveda 40:9]

Sambhuti means created things, for example table, chair, idol, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Vedas prohibit idol worship?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/do-the-vedas-prohibit-idol-worship)

Comment: The question is not duplicate that I can see, I'm looking for evidence that we should worship God via statue.  Veda and other scriptures say do not worship idols etc... ***I was told that we do not worship statue but worship God through statue*** - so I want to know where in the books it says that.

Comment: this is the link to the initial question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48497/25502 which was a duplicate and you will see the response, hence this Q

Comment: this is the link worship idols etc... not only 1 verse  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7683/25502

Comment: Your assumption that Vedas prohibit murti puja is not correct. The translation you've put is faluty as clarified very well in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/do-the-vedas-prohibit-idol-worship .

Comment: @sbharti the link you mention doesn't actually answer the above Veda quoted and very arguable what 1 particular person says.  my above link mentions other verses.  Some say can worship and some say cant worship Idol.  Regardless, where does it say can worship God via an idol?

Answer (score 4):

I checked the verse given in the question. It has nothing to do with idol worship.

> andham tamah pravisanti yesambhutim upasate tato bhuya iva te tamo ya
> sambhutyam ratah
>
> Into blinding darkness enter those who worhip the unmanifest and into
> still greater darkness, as it were, those who delight in the manifest.

**Isa Upanishad 12**

> asambhuti: the unmanifest, the undifferentiated prakrti. We get our
> rewards according to our beliefs.
>
> asambhuti: non-becoming: Those who
> do not believe in re-birth may be referred to.
>
> sambhuti: the manifest,
> the lord of the phenomenal world, karya-brahma, Hiranya-garbha.
> Sankara [Adi Sankara's interpretation of sambhuti]. It is sometimes said that asambhuti means that the world has
> no creator, that it is produced, preserved and destroyed by its own
> nature. Those who hold such view are the naturalists. See Bhagavad
> Gita xvi.8,9,20.
>
> The Supreme is neither of these in the sense that he is not also the
> other. If we identify the Supreme with the manifest, it would be
> pantheism in the sense that the whole of the Divine nature finds
> expression in the manifested world, leaving nothing over, and it is a
> wrong view. Again, if the world of becoming were not there, it would
> also disappear in what would seem a world of undifferentiated
> abstraction. Within the depths of the spirit there is unfolded before
> us the drama of God's dealings with man and man's with God. Unity and
> multiplicity are both aspects of the Supreme and therefore the nature
> of the Supreme is said to be inconceivable.

**The Principal Upanishads, Isa Upanishad 12, Commentary by S. Radhakrishnan**

> One thing they say, is obtained from the worship of the manifested;
> another they say, from the worship of the unmanifested. Thus we have
> heard from the wise who taught us this.

**Isa Upanishad 13**

> One thing etc.: As a result of worshipping Hiranyagarbha, the devotee
> obtains such supernatural powers as the ability to reduce himself to
> the size of an atom, to make himself light as a feather, and to
> pervade the entire universe. These are characteristics of
> Hiranyagarbha.
>
> Another etc: According to the Puranas, the result of such worship is
> absorption in prakriti.
>
> The scriptures say that whatever a person worships he becomes after
> death. He who worships Prakriti, characterized by nescience, remains
> merged in prakriti for untold years. And he who worships
> Hiranyagarbha, who is only a manifestation of Prakriti, obtains a
> corresponding result.

**Isa Upanishad 13, commentary of Swami Nikahilananda**

Basically you will get powers by worshipping Hiranyagarbha but will remain at the level of Prakriti. Hiranyagarbha is a manifestation of Lord Brahma at the level of Prakriti. Worshipping Lord Brahma as pure Consciousness will lead to moksha while worshipping Hiranyagarbha will lead to complete mastery of Prakriti.

**Here are two examples of scripture supporting Murthi puja.**

> Till the realisation of perfect knowledge a man should continue the
> ritualistic worship of Shiva. 59-60. In order to convince the world,
> the rituals must be continued.
>
> Just as the sun is reflected in many vessels, in the same manner, O
> devas, know that the supreme Brahman, Shiva, assumes the form of
> whatever is seen or heard in the world real or unreal. There is
> difference in vessels but not in the water they contain.
>
> This is what those who know the real meaning of the Vedas say. "Lord
> Shiva is within the heart of beings in this world." Of what avail are
> images to those who have the real knowledge?
>
> **Having an image is very auspicious for a person who has no such
> knowledge. It is a ladder that enables him to climb to a higher
> position.**
>
> It is very difficult to climb to a position without a support. **The
> image is only a means to achieve the Nirguna Shiva.**
>
> The attainment of the Nirguna through a Saguna is certainly possible.
> In this manner, **the symbols of all lords are conductive to steady
> faith and belief**.
>
> This lord is very great and this is the mode of worship of that lord.
> **If there is no image, of what avail are scents, sandal paste, flowers
> etc?**
>
> Till the realisation of true knowledge, **the image shall necessarily be
> worshipped. If any one does not worship the image before he attains
> perfect knowledge, his downfall is sure.**

**Shiva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Section I, Creation, Chapter 12**

> Whoever makes an offering to Me with devotion, be it of leaf, flower,
> fruit or water - that devout offering made by a pure-hearted man, I
> accept with joy.

**Gita 9.26**

**Where would you put these offerings if there is no murthi or image?**

There is also warning not to regard a murthi as mere stone.

> **To perdition he goes who regards** the Guru as human, the Mantra as mere
> letters and **the Images as stone**.

**Kularnava Tantra, Devotion to Guru, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

Comment: @ Pradip you have taken this out of context - making an offering  with Good heart is not the same as saying worshiping God via Idol - see also the the link above which relates to Idol worship this mentions many verses.  Arguably, based on your point there are contradictions. Doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Where would you put the offerings suggested by the Gita in the absence of a murthi?

Comment: 1) you quote does not say put offering in front of Image / murthi - provide a quote that says that otherwise that's just your belief.  2) take fruit for example - what benefit is the fruit for anyone if you put in front of an idol, it cannot eat the fruit, its going to go off and wasted.  God doesn't need fruit.  3) my understanding would be that you give fruit to poor people as a Godly act ***that's devotion***.  otherwise no benefit to anyone.  4) either way doesn't answer, where does it say you worship God via idol?

Comment: No commentator says that the verse quoted by you is talking about idol worship. I have now explicitly posted an entire section that says that without image worship a beginner will fail.

Comment: You really need to read my question - does it say anywhere we should worship God via an image / idol / statue?  so the answer would be yes and provide a quote or No no such quote.  The quote I mention is an example of not worshiping xyz.  see link question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7683/25502.  Where is you post about image worship?

Comment: ok you amended your answer I'll have a look

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay you amended answer does not prove your point, just what you want it to interpret.  Even if my quote (taken from another question) is wrong, you still have not answered my Q.

Comment: question amended for clarity - clear scriptures that say worship via idol

Comment: @anothertheory, Shiva Purana quote given above clearly says that one has to worship the image. You seem to have missed the quote.

Comment: @MrGreenGold, I have explained that by Sankara is meant Adi Sankara's interpretation of Sambhuti. As for the effect of worshipping Hiranyagarbha I will add some of the following verses of Isa Upanishad.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay your answer and that similar questions above do answer the question to a certain extent but has conflict with other verses, also appears to be an issue of translation.  Many thanks for your assistance.